# Garbled characters in cmd window?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have met some garbled character in cmd window.
It usually show this when I type `echo %date%`
[image]

but in some other server,it shows "??"

[image]

How does this happen?
they are the same windows server 2008 system.

I have found that the second has no default code page option? why? how to fix it?

the first one is this :

[image]

and the second is this:
[image]

Comment: What's the locale on the servers?

Comment: I have found the issue is that the second server has no defalut code page

Comment: Check and compare the **Font** tab of _Console Window Properties_. Check `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" /V ACP` and `reg query … /V OEMCP`